# express.js not waiting for loop

Tags: javascript, express

I would like to make users detail json but my code not waiting for loop
and print {"personalchats":[]}

I would like send after for loop

how can i fix this problem?

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM personalchat WHERE user1ID = ? OR user2ID = ?", [userID, userID], function(err, row, fields) {
  if (err)
    console.log(err);

  else {
    personalchats = Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
      if (row[i].user1ID != userID)
        user2ID = row[i].user1ID;
      else
        user2ID = row[i].user2ID;

      connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID = ?", [user2ID], function(err2, row2, fields2) {
        if (err)
          console.log(err2);

        else {


          personalchats.push({
            'success': true,
            'userID': row2[0].userID,
            'name': row2[0].name,
            'surname': row2[0].surname,
            'email': row2[0].email
          });
          console.log(personalchats);
        }


      });

    }

    res.send({
      "personalchats": personalchats
    });
  }

});
```

Comment: most probably `connection.query` is returning a promise, so you can use `.then()` on it and inside the callback use `res.send({ personalchats: personalchats })`. This approach will send information only for one user. Afterwards you can improve the solution to `Promise.all` and create an array of promises e.g. `promises.push(connection)` on each iteration. Then use `Promise.all(promises).then(() => res.send(.....))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM personalchat WHERE user1ID = ? OR user2ID = ?", [userID, userID], function(err, row, fields) {
  if (err)
    console.log(err);

  else {
      personalchats = [];
      var userIDs = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        if (row[i].user1ID != userID)
          userIDs.push(row[i].user1ID);
        else
          userIDs.push(row[i].user2ID);
      }

      connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID in (" + userIDs.join(',') + ")", function(err2, row2, fields2) {
        if (err)
          console.log(err2);

        else {

          row2.forEach(r =>
            personalchats.push({
              'success': true,
              'userID': r.userID,
              'name': r.name,
              'surname': r.surname,
              'email': r.email
            });
          })
          console.log(personalchats);
          res.send({
            "personalchats": personalchats
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running into asynchronous problems. Your calls to the database take time to complete, and there is a strong chance you won’t have received a response and ran the callback before you are trying to send that data. Working with ‘Promise.all’ might be a good idea in this case or building out some type of function that gets run after pushing each item to the array inside the callback that will check to see if all the responses have been received before sending the express response.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is asynchronous. First `connection.query` returns result by calling your callback `function(err, row, fields)  { }`.

The second query also returns by calling callback function `function(err2, row2, fields2) { }`. You can read the values from within that callback function. You can log as `console.log(personalchats)`. Also you have to send the result in that callback function.

```
  personalchats.push({
    'success': true,
    'userID': row2[0].userID,
    'name': row2[0].name,
    'surname': row2[0].surname,
    'email': row2[0].email
  });
  console.log(personalchats);
  res.send({
    "personalchats": personalchats
  });
```

Otherwise values of `row2` will not be available outside the callback.

You should send the result after `connection.query` success. Complete example:

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM personalchat WHERE user1ID = ? OR user2ID = ?", [userID, userID], function(err, row, fields) {
  if (err)
    console.log(err);

  else {
    personalchats = Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
      if (row[i].user1ID != userID)
        user2ID = row[i].user1ID;
      else
        user2ID = row[i].user2ID;

      connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID = ?", [user2ID], function(err2, row2, fields2) {
        if (err)
          console.log(err2);

        else {


          personalchats.push({
            'success': true,
            'userID': row2[0].userID,
            'name': row2[0].name,
            'surname': row2[0].surname,
            'email': row2[0].email
          });
          console.log(personalchats);
          res.send({
            "personalchats": personalchats
          });
        }


      });

    }


  }

});
```